# Как обозначить, что «сейчас» относится к «оделся»?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Как обозначить, что ***сейчас*** относится к ***оделся*** в предложении:

*Я уже почти оделся сейчас и выхожу.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отнеенность "сейчас" к одному из однородных сказуемых определяется по его позиции в предложении (до или поле союза И):

(1) Я **сейчас** уже почти **оделся** и выхожу.

(2) Я уже почти оделся и **сейчас выхож**у.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что даже необязательно писать "сейчас", т.к. само предложение говорит о происходящем в данный момент.

"Я уже почти оделся и выхожу" вполне достаточно.

У глагола "оделся" совершенный вид, "почти" говорит о незавершённости действия, у глагола "выхожу" время настоящее, так что вполне понятно, что события в предложении происходят в данный момент.

Я бы не стал утяжелять конструкцию.

Но я не филолог и не лингвист, так что вполне могу быть неправ.

Comment: Как обозначить, что сейчас относится к оделся?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд ничего тут переобозначать не надо. Всё и так понятно. А если бы и было непонятно, что к чему относится, на смысл это вряд ли повлияет. 
Все равно ведь, если "выхожу", то это тоже "сейчас". И "уже оделся" - это все равно "сейчас", есть оно там или нет.

Вообще на мой взгляд "сейчас" тут лишнее.